# Email Authentication error using nodemailer and AWS Lambda

Tags: email, aws-lambda, nodemailer, hotmail

I'm trying to send an email through nodemailer (a nodejs package). The issue is that while this works on my desktop, it gives me an authentication error when I run the exact same code on AWS Lambda.

Here's the code:

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const otpGenerator = require('otp-generator');
async function main() {
    try {
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: "hotmail",
            auth: {
                user: 'something@hotmail.com',
                pass: 'password'
            }
        });
        
        let otp = await otpGenerator.generate(6, {
          upperCaseAlphabets: false,
          specialChars: false,
        });
        const html = `<html><head></head><body><div>Here's your OTP: <b>${otp}</b><br><br>This is an automated message - please do not respond. </p></body></html>`;
        var subject = "OTP";
        
        var mailOptions = {
          from: 'something@hotmail.com',
              to: 'recipient@gmail.com',
              bcc: 'something@hotmail.com',
              subject:  subject,
              html
        };
        const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
        console.log(`Email sent: ${info.messageId}`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw new Error(err)
    }
}
main();
```

Anyone got any ideas what i'm missing?
I was originally trying to send mail through gmail but it seemed to require a whole lot of extra stuff like 2FA, app passwords and what not but hotmail seemed to work... until i tried it on Lambda and it wont.

Comment: Hi and welcome. *an authentication error* is sadly very vague. Can you expand more by updating the question with the textual output of what you see in the CloudWatch logs?